# Ubuntu 18.04.6: Using llvmpipe instead of AMD Radeon HD 5570

Tags: drivers, 18.04, graphics, amd-graphics, radeon

I am on an ancient HP TouchSmart 610 with Ubuntu 18.04.6 LTS installed

Recently my system has been using llvmpipe instead of my GPU (which is an AMD Radeon HD 5570) therefore using the PC is more sluggish

I have tried other methods which did not work, booting into Windows gives me a blue screen with error code "video_tdr_failure"

Info:

Input: `inxi -G`

```
           Display Server: x11 (X.Org 1.19.6 )
           drivers: ati,radeon (unloaded: modesetting,fbdev,vesa)
           Resolution: 1920x1080@60.00hz
           OpenGL: renderer: llvmpipe (LLVM 10.0.0, 128 bits)
           version: 3.3 Mesa 20.0.8
```

Input: `lspci -nnk | grep -iA2 VGA`

```
    Subsystem: Micro-Star International Co., Ltd. [MSI] Mobility Radeon HD 5570 [1462:2241]
    Kernel driver in use: radeon
```

Input: `dmesg | grep radeon` (This one seems to be long)

```
[   26.531921] fb: switching to radeondrmfb from VESA VGA
[   26.532550] radeon 0000:01:00.0: VRAM: 1024M 0x0000000000000000 - 0x000000003FFFFFFF (1024M used)
[   26.532552] radeon 0000:01:00.0: GTT: 1024M 0x0000000040000000 - 0x000000007FFFFFFF
[   26.533374] [drm] radeon: 1024M of VRAM memory ready
[   26.533375] [drm] radeon: 1024M of GTT memory ready.
[   26.721005] [drm] radeon: dpm initialized
[   26.822964] radeon 0000:01:00.0: WB enabled
[   26.822967] radeon 0000:01:00.0: fence driver on ring 0 use gpu addr 0x0000000040000c00 and cpu addr 0x00000000f2e50062
[   26.822968] radeon 0000:01:00.0: fence driver on ring 3 use gpu addr 0x0000000040000c0c and cpu addr 0x0000000005448d91
[   26.823166] radeon 0000:01:00.0: fence driver on ring 5 use gpu addr 0x000000000005c418 and cpu addr 0x00000000510f26de
[   26.823170] radeon 0000:01:00.0: radeon: MSI limited to 32-bit
[   26.823221] radeon 0000:01:00.0: radeon: using MSI.
[   26.823244] [drm] radeon: irq initialized.
[   28.010038] [drm:uvd_v1_0_start [radeon]] *ERROR* UVD not responding, trying to reset the VCPU!!!
[   29.023087] [drm:uvd_v1_0_start [radeon]] *ERROR* UVD not responding, trying to reset the VCPU!!!
[   30.036427] [drm:uvd_v1_0_start [radeon]] *ERROR* UVD not responding, trying to reset the VCPU!!!
[   31.050910] [drm:uvd_v1_0_start [radeon]] *ERROR* UVD not responding, trying to reset the VCPU!!!
[   32.067739] [drm:uvd_v1_0_start [radeon]] *ERROR* UVD not responding, trying to reset the VCPU!!!
[   33.085146] [drm:uvd_v1_0_start [radeon]] *ERROR* UVD not responding, trying to reset the VCPU!!!
[   34.099154] [drm:uvd_v1_0_start [radeon]] *ERROR* UVD not responding, trying to reset the VCPU!!!
[   35.113946] [drm:uvd_v1_0_start [radeon]] *ERROR* UVD not responding, trying to reset the VCPU!!!
[   36.128783] [drm:uvd_v1_0_start [radeon]] *ERROR* UVD not responding, trying to reset the VCPU!!!
[   37.144604] [drm:uvd_v1_0_start [radeon]] *ERROR* UVD not responding, trying to reset the VCPU!!!
[   37.164471] [drm:uvd_v1_0_start [radeon]] *ERROR* UVD not responding, giving up!!!
[   37.164477] radeon 0000:01:00.0: failed initializing UVD (-1).
[   38.172121] [drm:r600_ib_test [radeon]] *ERROR* radeon: fence wait timed out.
[   38.172158] [drm:radeon_ib_ring_tests [radeon]] *ERROR* radeon: failed testing IB on GFX ring (-110).
[   38.172176] [drm:radeon_device_init [radeon]] *ERROR* ib ring test failed (-110).
[   38.209701] fbcon: radeondrmfb (fb0) is primary device
[   38.230128] radeon 0000:01:00.0: fb0: radeondrmfb frame buffer device
[   38.240033] [drm] Initialized radeon 2.50.0 20080528 for 0000:01:00.0 on minor 0
```

I also looked up about "UVD not responding, trying to reset the VCPU", no solutions were found either

**Can this problem be fixed or does it mean that the GPU is failing?** All answers are appreciated

Comment: *"does it mean that the GPU is failing"* -- Let me ask you this: if this were an Ubuntu problem, then why would you be getting a blue screen when you boot Windows?